# Greek text on android utf8 not show properly

Tags: android, encoding, android-studio

I'm making app with Greek text and data but not every letter is shown.
Letter which is not shown not make `?` mark but just white space. File encoding is set to `utf8` and in `build.gradle`, I have set compile for `utf8`.

For example: `(agapó) ἀγαπῶ (ἀγαπᾶν)` in listview is shown as `(agapó) γαπ (γαπ ν)`. Even button on XML not shown properly same problem.

The screenshot:

[image]

```
  private void inicialization() {

    sound = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sound);
    home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
    home.setOnClickListener(this);

    setData();

    listwords = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listwords);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.adapteritem, R.id.greek_word, Timeslist);
    listwords.setAdapter(adapter);
    listwords.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
    tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
    tv5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text5);

    setPlayer();
}

private void setData() {

    int index;
    index = getIntent().getIntExtra("index", 0);

    switch (index){
        case 0:
            if(lang){
                Timeslist = GlobalTimes.Times1ListCZ; // from global class of arrays
                TimesAudio = GlobalTimes.Times1AudioCZ;
                TimesWords = GlobalTimes.Times1WordsCZ;
            }
            if(!lang){
                Timeslist =  GlobalTimes.Times1List;
                TimesAudio = GlobalTimes.Times1Audio;
                TimesWords = GlobalTimes.Times1Words;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And the data from Globalclass

```
public class GlobalTimes {

public static String[] Times1List = { "(agapó) ἀγαπῶ (ἀγαπᾶν)", "(agó) ἄγω", "(airó) αἴρω", "(akúó) ἀκούω", "(hamartanó) ἁμαρτάνω", "(anabainó) ἀναβαίνω"};
public static Integer[] Times1Audio = { R.raw.miluji, R.raw.vedu, R.raw.zdviham, R.raw.slysim, R.raw.hresim, R.raw.jdunahoru };
public static String[][] Times1Words = {

        {
                "ἀγαπῶ",     
                "ἀγαπᾶν",    
                "ἀγαπήσω",   
                "ἠγάπησα",  
                "ἠγάπηκα",   
                "ἠγάπημαι",  
                "ἠγαπήθην", 
                "miluji"
        },
        {
                "ἄγω",
                "x",
                "ἄξω",
         ...
         ...
```

My adapteritem.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/greek_word"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FF000000"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

Build.gradle under SRC this should automaticaly set UT8...

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
options.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

}

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED BY

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Use typeface Times new roman.ttf and apply to textview by override the adapter method !!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "times.ttf");
```

and then just make an object of this class a refer it to an listadapter

```
 public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public Context context;
    public String[] values;
    private Typeface font;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values, Typeface font) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapteritem, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.font = font;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapteritem, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.greek_word);

        textView.setTypeface(font);
        textView.setText(values[position]); // maybe not the best line of code but i dont know how do it better.. but works :)

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: is these letters coming dynamically or static data?

Comment: static data for example    {
                    "ἀγαπῶ",     
                    "ἀγαπᾶν",    
                    "ἀγαπήσω",   
                    "ἠγάπησα",   
                    "ἠγάπηκα", 
                    "ἠγάπημαι",  
                    "ἠγαπήθην",  
                    "miluji"   
            }

Comment: u are using textview? can u plz paste ur code too

Comment: no iam putting the data into Listview

Comment: y dont u use custom listview and set these in textview

Comment: what u mean ? i add adapteritem.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your editor (Eclipse) doesn't save the files as UTF-8?

Anyway, such strings should be stored in [Android String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). As these files are XML files it is very unlikely to have encoding problems.

Edit: Even in Android Studio you can have this problem. You can check it here:
[image]

Comment: iam using Android Studio and when i right click on android studio whatever i want i choose File encoding i have it set to UTF8 and in Build.gradle i have set encoding to utf8 look at edit.

Comment: i have set UTF8 even there like on your screenshot

Comment: Try to place a (new) TextView where you set the text directly in the layout file. Use a word where one of the characters are lost. Does the TextView render the word correctly?

Comment: Ok. Then I think it could be some kind of Font problem. Are these (non-visible) character so special? Are they taken from the standard greek alphabet? How do you construct the accents like '? Are the two keystrokes on your keyboard?

Comment: i dont have them on my keybord.. and yes they are special because they arent in standard greek aplhabet because some characters have "comas ," and "'" and so on.. What u exactly mean by that ascent like "'?" ? I have Czech keyborad.. But i dont think is matter of font maybe is but could i change font to (times new roman) for displaying on device ? and how? and Will be difference ?

Comment: Find out whether these special characters are displayed on your device in some way, e.g. does Android browser show these characters? Can you enter one of these characters e.g. in a new email? If you send yourself a mail, are these characters visible on Android? For font changes please open a new Question or better search for existing ones.

Comment: i will try apply a Typeface

Comment: You could give some more info to the readers how you changed the font and flag my comment regarding font as helpful.