# haw can i print in greek?

Tags: android, zebra-printers

hello I want to ask a question..I have made a button and when I press that button it sends the information that I want to print at a printer and I  want to print in Greek and if I change ASCII it doesn't print Greek it prints some symbols. any help would be perfect .. thank you.. this is my code

```
 final byte delimiter = 10;

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {

                    try {

                        int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {

                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            inputStream.read(packetBytes);

                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {

                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {

                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(
                                            readBuffer, 0,
                                            encodedBytes, 0,
                                            encodedBytes.length
                                    );

                                    // specify US-ASCII encoding
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;
```

Comment: maybe this is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855029/greek-text-on-android-utf8-not-show-properly

Answer (score 0):

You have no info here about the format you are printing. You need to format your label to use UTF-8 as well.

see: [Unicode characters on ZPL printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer)